# Bluetooth module not found when running qml bluetooth scanner on android

Tags: android, qt, bluetooth, qml

I installed qt5.2 for android and I'm while I'm trying to run an app on my android device whose code is

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtBluetooth 5.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

the app won't run and I get this application output

```
Starting remote process.D/dalvikvm(31265): Late-enabling CheckJNI
D/dalvikvm(31265): GC_CONCURRENT freed 245K, 11% free 7211K/8071K, paused 12ms+2ms,   total 27ms
D/dalvikvm(31265): GC_CONCURRENT freed 455K, 14% free 7231K/8327K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm(31265): Trying to load lib    /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x417ddb68, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(31265): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Core.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Core.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Network.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): Added shared lib  /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Network.so 0x417ddb68
I/Qt      (31265): Network start
D/dalvikvm(31265): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0x417ddb68, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(31265): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0x417ddb68, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(31265): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0x417ddb68, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(31265): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0x417ddb68, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(31265): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Widgets.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Widgets.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5Widgets.so 0x417ddb68, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(31265): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroidGL.so  0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroidGL.so 0x417ddb68
I/Qt      (31265): qt start
W/dalvikvm(31265): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtMessageDialogHelper' 

D/dalvikvm(31265): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): Shared lib  '/data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so' already loaded in same   CL 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): Trying to load lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libapp1.so 0x417ddb68
D/Qt      (31265): qml/qqmlengine.cpp:1451 (QQmlDebuggingEnabler::QQmlDebuggingEnabler(bool)): QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
D/dalvikvm(31265): Added shared lib /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libapp1.so 0x417ddb68
D/dalvikvm(31265): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/org.qtproject.example.app1/lib/libapp1.so 0x417ddb68, skipping init
W/Qt      (31265): kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp:416  (QCoreApplicationPrivate::QCoreApplicationPrivate(int&, char**, uint)): WARNING:  QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
W/dalvikvm(31265): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNativeInputConnection'
W/dalvikvm(31265): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtExtractedText'
D/libEGL  (31265): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
D/libEGL  (31265): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
D/libEGL  (31265): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
D/        (31265): Device driver API match
D/        (31265): Device driver API version: 10
D/        (31265): User space API version: 10 
D/        (31265): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST  2012 
D/AbsListView(31265): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/dalvikvm(31265): GC_CONCURRENT freed 439K, 13% free 7263K/8327K, paused 2ms+12ms, total 35ms
W/InputEventReceiver(31265): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event  receiver has already been disposed.
D/AbsListView(31265): Get MotionRecognitionManager
W/libEGL  (31265): eglTerminate() called w/ 1 objects remaining
W/SurfaceView(31265): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false  sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true  realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
I/AndroidRuntime(31265): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
```

but it compiles and runs as a desktop app with no errors 
 
**Update:** it runs on my device if i comment out the `import QtBluetooth 5.0` but I'm trying to make an app to use the bluetooth of my device so I need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QtBluetooth does not support Android at the moment, so this is expected.

Please refer to the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/qt5/qt52#bluetooth_nfc) for details.

> The new Qt Bluetooth module allows you to retrieve information about local Bluetooth devices, scan and retrieve information about devices in range, push files to devices and connect to them using RFCOMM. Qt Bluetooth module is currently supported only for Linux (on BlueZ 4.x) and BlackBerry.

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753662/bluetooth-communication-with-qt-5-2-on-android/20771456#20771456) from today in a different thread for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is the page of supported features in Qt 5.2 I should have read them before asking http://qt-project.org/wiki/New-Features-in-Qt-5.2

Comment: @redshark: :-) If you read my other answer further on, you will find that BogDan from KDAB may make it work for 5.3 which is probably released around summer time next year, hopefully.